# In the contoller, how do i obtain data from an http post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, http-post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to obtain data from a form using method=“post”? How to request it data in my controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550707/how-to-obtain-data-from-a-form-using-method-post-how-to-request-it-data-in-my)

I want to simply obtain data from a form.. Below is my form.. In my controller , how do i access the data from the form?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SavePersonButton").click(function () {
            $("#addPerson").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
<h2>Add Person</h2>
<form id="addPerson" method="post" action="<%: Url.Action("SavePerson","Prod") %>">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="tableHeader">New Person</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="label">First Name:</td>
            <td class="content">
                <input type="text" maxlength="20" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" />
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="label">Last Name:</td>
            <td class="content">
                <input type="text" maxlength="20" name="LastName" id="LastName" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="tableFooter">
                    <br />
                    <a id ="SavePersonButton" href="#" class="regularButton">Add</a>
                    <a href="javascript:history.back()" class="regularButton">Cancel</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Contoller Controller Controller Controller Controller

```
[HTTP POST]
public  Action Result(Could i pass in the name through here or..)
{

Can obtain the data from the html over here using Request.Form. Pleas help
return RedirectToAction("SearchPerson", "Person");
}
```

Comment: you have posted the same question twice

Comment: @gilly3 it is raised accidentally by same OP few minutes ago

Comment: @HatSoft - That comment is generated automatically when someone votes to close a question as duplicate.  Are you suggesting it's not a duplicate question?

Comment: @gilly3 hmmm i did not knew that cheers mate

Answer (score 4):

Just make sure the parameters of the action has the same name as the input fields and the data-binding will take care of the rest for you.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(string inputfieldName1, int inputFieldName2 ...)
{
    // You can now access the form data through the parameters

    return RedirectToAction("SearchPerson", "Person");
}
```

If you have a model whose properties have the same name as your input fields your could even do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(YourOwnModel model)
{
    // You will now get a model of type YourOwnModel, 
    // with properties based on the form data

    return RedirectToAction("SearchPerson", "Person");
}
```

*Notice that the attribute should be `[HttpPost]` not `[HTTP POST]`.*

It is of course possible to read the data through `Request.Form` as well:

```
var inputData = Request.Form["inputFieldName"];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction (FormCollection form)
{
    var inputOne = form["FirstName"];

    return RedirectToAction("SearchPerson", "Person");
}
```