# How do i pull user entered text data from a view for http POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have written a basic `GET` method for my `CheckoutController` that returns the view, the view will have text boxes for my user to enter payment information and promo code. How do I access this data in the `POST` method?

```
 // GET: Checkout
    public ActionResult PaymentsAndPromotions()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PaymentsAndPromotions()
    {
        var order = new Order();
        try
        {
            if (db.Promotions !== PromoCode)
            {
                return View(order);
            }
            else
            {
                //save the order
                db.Orders.Add(order);
                db.SaveChanges();
                //process the order
                var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
                cart.CreateOrder(order);

                return RedirectToAction("Complete", new object{id = order.OrderID});

            }

        }

        catch 
        {
            //invalid - redisplay with error
            return View(order);
        }
    }
```

View code:

```
<form>
Payment Method:<br /><br />
Credit Card #: <br />
<input type="text" name="CreditCardNum" /><br />
Credit Card Type: <br />
<input type="text" name="CreditCardType" /><br/>

Promo Code: <br />
<input type="text" name="PromoCode"/> <br />
```

Comment: Your GET and POST methods, the model you passing to the view, and the view (just needs to include a few properties)

Comment: Your question seems quite similar to these two http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550947/in-the-contoller-how-do-i-obtain-data-from-an-http-post?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550707/how-to-obtain-data-from-a-form-using-method-post-how-to-request-it-data-in-my

Comment: @adirks95, You really need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to understand the basics. See jomsk1e answer for the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create a model something like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public string CreditCardNum { get;set; }
    public string CreditCardType { get;set; }
    public string PromoCode { get;set; }
}
```

And from your controller, do this:

```
public ActionResult PaymentsAndPromotions()
{
    var order = new Order();

    return View(order);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PaymentsAndPromotions(Order order)
{

    //you can get all your order's property here. 
    //example:
    if (order.CreditCardNum != "test123")
    {

    }

    return View(order);
}
```

In your view, you can do something like this (assuming you are using razor syntax):

```
@model Models.Order

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreditCardNum)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreditCardType)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PromoCode)

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

Comment: instead of hard coding for creditcard number could i do Form["CreditCardNum"]?

Comment: not sure if I got your question correctly, you mean at postback? you can use order.CreditCardNum. But I think Form["CreditCardNum"] will also do. Try it to see for yourself. That's how we learn. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

**adirks95**, in controller you can fetch form data using such code: `Request.Form["CreditCardNum"]`. Please let me know if you still have any issues.

Comment: as such?  
    public ActionResult PaymentsAndPromotions(FormCollection form)
        {
            var CCNum = form["CreditCardNum"];

Comment: would the above work? if not how do i implement the request.form["CreditCardNum"]?

Comment: Request - is a static class, can you access it?